# How to execute command with bash script inside Ubuntu, which was started with bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

How to execute command with bash script inside Ubuntu, which was started with bash script?

for example with ssh I'm accessing ubuntu. How to run command inside opened ubuntu. If I write it in bash script after ssh command it will get executed as soon as I exit out of this environment.

How to execute bash script inside this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you are asking how to start a command on a remote machine with ssh?  That would be:

```
ssh user@hostname your_script_name-here
```

There are some command line args that affect the remote command, like `-f`.  If this is indeed what you are asking about then the ssh man page is mostly your friend.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is very much easy,

you need to install Secure Shell (SSH) / Secure FTP (SFTP) Server in Ubuntu. then go through the recommended level of security settings to run an SSH server to be able to execute terminal commands or transfer files securely.

for reference check out the [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWr6VCgLxBs) video and this [tutorial](https://chrisjean.com/ssh-tutorial-for-ubuntu-linux/) as well.

Comment: thanks, but maybe my question wasn't pretty clear. It's the following: my first command in bash script is: "ssh user@server.com". when I run this command I'm accessing Ubuntu. Then inside ubuntu I want to run "ls" command. But if I type this command inside bash script it gets executed after i exit my ubuntu server. I need it to be executed inside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do.
Do you want to bash a script for example
`./main.py`
so that the script doesn't stop when you leave the SSH-connection? If that's your question, try `./main.py &` !

Comment: my first command in bash script is: "ssh user@server.com". when I run this command I'm accessing Ubuntu. Then inside ubuntu I want to run "ls" command. But if I type this command inside bash script it gets executed after i exit my ubuntu server. I need it to be executed inside.

Comment: The `ls` command just prints something (the objects in your current folder) in the console. What do you mean with it gets executed when you executed?  can you please post your complete Code and what you want to do??